# Is it Possible to Sort (Colored) Cells After They Have Been Conditionally Formatted?

Tags: excel

I have formatted 6 cells in a row based on three colors (green, red, and black). One cell is green, two are red, and three are black. Is there a way to sort these from green - red - black because sorting them manually does not work.

Comment: I have Excel 2013, and in my question I said sorting manually won't work apparently because I conditionally formatted the cells that I want to sort.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Excel 2007, but I suspect available in all later versions also:

[image: SO21839535 first example]

Re OP's comment "This doesn't help" maybe I should have taken `I have formatted 6 cells in a row` literally:

[image: SO21839535 second example]

Comment: How did you sort by $, I don't have that option, and what does that even do when sorting by $?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the usual way to sort doesn't work here. The numbers inside the cells sort out, but the colors are static and remain in the cell they were in. I'm not sure why this is, but as I said before, I suspect it's because the cells have been conditionally formatted. Is there some other way to sort these cells based on color, or am I outta luck?

Comment: I have no idea how to add a link to my file.